# OpenGL: What distances in 3D space are reasonable?

Tags: opengl

I've discovered that my shadow cubemap for my point light works less and less well the further my objects get from my light. The framebuffer and attached depth renderbuffer and color texture are 3000x3000 pixels.

At a distance of about 4000 units they looks really silly:
[image]

At a distance of just about 200 units, it's looking much better (I will probably work out how to do soft shadows next).
[image]

At even greater distances, nothing is getting written to the depth buffer of the shadow pass at all. I'm attributing that to the fact that the further away from the light source viewpoint my object is, it eventually gets to a point where it uses less than a pixel?

I've also noticed that at very large scale, my objects seem to... deteriorate, so that half the triangles aren't drawn.

With these in mind, what are the limits to the 3D distances that I should typically use? I'm creating a space scene, and I can scale the distances to some sort of good middle-ground, I'm just trying to work out what this middle ground is; and why exceeding it (or going even less) doesn't work.

Has it to do with the z-depth precision?

I assume that this also applies to scale. Are there any tips or tricks on how to handle scenes like a solar system. With very large distances, or, very small scales?

Comment: it more than likely has to do with the near and far plane of your light projection matrix

Comment: @ratchetfreak so should the near and far values be higher or lower?

Comment: They should be such that both your objects fall within it.

Comment: Yes. I've just tried varying it from `0.1,10000`. `0.1,100000000000000000000` and finally `1000,10000` (my objects are around 1400) the result is the same blocky shadow. It makes sense as the light is still projected from the same origin, regardless of the draw distance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect distance. You will always experience these artifacts, because your shadow is going to be projected on a bigger, and even more bigger surface area, the further you go.

The solution for your problem is [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch10.html). It's a low-cost adaptive method for tweaking  your shadows dynamically is mentioned in this tutorial. It is useful for complex scenes. If you plan your project to be as simple as it is now, then this is probably an over-engineering - instead just tweak your near/far planes of your shadow-map. Although I think, that the main problem here is that you use a point light, so I suppose your shadow-map is a cube-map? Much of the resolution in it is wasted.

Also, If you're planning to do a space simulation of some sorts, a point light might not be the best choice, since space is mostly empty. Most of your shadow-map resolution will go to waste. Instead, dedicate a directional light for each sun-planet pair, and calculate those when needed for rendering. The tutorial will teach how to adapt your shadow-mapping in order to combine more targets, depending on your view. It maximizes your use of shadow-mapping resolution.